# Down vote question from +1 to -1

Tags: support, voting, user-interface

I was attempting to remove a previous up vote of a question which was at +1, when I clicked down vote the question vote value went to -1 and not 0. Is this the expected behavior? I would have expected +1 to 0.

Comment: Was it your upvote that you were trying to remove?

Comment: You just click that upvote button again to remove your upvote.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to undo an upvote, just click the upvote button again.

Downvoting a question when you already upvoted it, does two things:

- Remove your upvote.
- Downvote the question.

That's why the question went from a score of +1 to -1.

Comment: I missed that they had previously upvoted. :-P